# how to fix acknowledge error canbus stm32

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, can-bus

I am working with `stm32f04c6` microprocessor.I've already sent data with canbus. now it does not work. status (tsr) code terro bit 1 is.

there is no ack

```
CAN error status register (CAN_ESR)

LEC[2:0]=011; 011: Acknowledgment Error
```

what should i do?

```
////can cubemx init.

 hcan.Instance = CAN;

 hcan.Init.Prescaler = 12;

 hcan.Init.Mode = CAN_MODE_NORMAL;

 hcan.Init.SyncJumpWidth = CAN_SJW_1TQ;

 hcan.Init.TimeSeg1 = CAN_BS1_13TQ;

 hcan.Init.TimeSeg2 = CAN_BS2_2TQ;

 hcan.Init.TimeTriggeredMode = DISABLE;

 hcan.Init.AutoBusOff = DISABLE;

 hcan.Init.AutoWakeUp = DISABLE;

 hcan.Init.AutoRetransmission = DISABLE;

 hcan.Init.ReceiveFifoLocked = DISABLE;

 hcan.Init.TransmitFifoPriority = DISABLE;

 if (HAL_CAN_Init(&hcan) != HAL_OK)

 {

  Error_Handler();

 }

 //filter config

sFilterConfig.FilterBank = 0;

sFilterConfig.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;

sFilterConfig.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_32BIT;

sFilterConfig.FilterIdHigh = 0x0000;

sFilterConfig.FilterIdLow = 0x0000;

sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdHigh = 0x0000;

sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdLow = 0x0000;

sFilterConfig.FilterFIFOAssignment = CAN_RX_FIFO0;

sFilterConfig.FilterActivation = ENABLE;

sFilterConfig.SlaveStartFilterBank = 14;

 if(HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&hcan, &sFilterConfig) != HAL_OK)

 {

 Error_Handler();

 }

 if (HAL_CAN_Start(&hcan) != HAL_OK)

 {

   Error_Handler();

 }

  /* Activate CAN RX notification*/

 if (HAL_CAN_ActivateNotification(&hcan, CAN_IT_RX_FIFO0_MSG_PENDING) != HAL_OK)

 {

  Error_Handler();

 }

  TxHeader.StdId = 0x4DE;//degiskene donecek

  TxHeader.ExtId = 0x01;//degiskene ..

  TxHeader.RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;

  TxHeader.IDE = CAN_ID_STD;

  TxHeader.DLC = 8;//degiskene ..

  TxHeader.TransmitGlobalTime = DISABLE;



///loop

while(1)

{

 do

 {

 freeTxMailBox=HAL_CAN_GetTxMailboxesFreeLevel(&hcan);

 }while(freeTxMailBox!=3);

 if (HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan, &TxHeader, paketDataSekiz, &TxMailbox) != HAL_OK);
}
```

Comment: Please take time and properly format your code.

Comment: Could be the classic problem: is there another CAN node present on the bus?

Comment: yes . there is i 7565 h1 (usbcan converter). similar  code works stm3210ceval with i 7565 h1 but similer code doesn't work stm32f04c6 with i7565 h1. previously worked at two stm.

Comment: And what makes you think it is a software error? Are there CAN frames appearing on the bus? Have you listened to the bus with scope or CAN analyser?

Comment: I checked stm32f04 with a multimeter. there isnt problem. i7565h1 has a 120 ohm bus line.it works with stm3210ceval. i checked stm3210ceval with oscilloscope canbus line there  is ack bit. on the other hand  i checked stm32f04 with oscilloscope canbus line.  there is not ack bit. i have no idea about the error.